Как на в сделать обводку для 3D объектов?
Мне нужно написать мобильное приложение, которое будет составлять карту высот.
Решил выбрать unity для разработки, так как там когда-то работал. Плюс в нём удобнее работать с 3д миром.
И начал я разработку. Быстро написал скриптик, который будет создавать "Зону"
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlaneBuilderScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int width = 10;
    [SerializeField] private int height = 10;
    [SerializeField] private int levels = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float spacing = 0.5f;

    [SerializeField] private Material outlineMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject planesContainer;
    void Start()
    {
        BuildPlanes();
    }

    void BuildPlanes()
    {
        
        for (int level = 0; level < levels; level++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
                {
                    CreateRectangle(x, z, level);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateRectangle(int x, int z, int level)
    {
        // Создаем прямоугольник (квадрат) размером 1x1 метр
        GameObject rectangle = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        rectangle.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0.01f, 1);
        rectangle.transform.position = new Vector3(x, level * spacing, z);
        rectangle.name = $"Rectangle_{x}_{z}_{level}";

        rectangle.transform.parent = planesContainer.transform;
    }

}

Создается вот такое поле:


И возник вопрос. Как мне сделать, чтобы прямоугольники были между собою различимы? Я решил, что надо добавить линии, которые будут их отделять друг от друга, но столкнулся с проблемой, что компонент outline ничего не меняет для 3d объекта.
Мне нужно, чтобы получилось что-то вроде таких линий (без свечения):


Карта из сетки делается не аутлайном, а шейдером. Transparent шейдер, который рисует линии на mesh в локальных координатах объекта с заданным размером тайла и шириной. Его нужно написать самому или сделать в ShaderGraph. Либо множество LineRenderer, но это транжирство ресурсов, лучше пару дней поучиться ShaderGraph, что даст очень много новых возможностей.

@Yaroslav спасибо за совет. Может знаете какой-то ресурс, где можно изучить? Потому как смотрел, но не находил тех элементов, которые есть у тех, кто записывает ролики.

Есть готовые скрипты
Вот чем пользуюсь я обводки: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/quick-outline-115488
Вот что может ещё пригодится:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/outline-toolkit-98020
Также можешь сам поискать на площадке другие outline инструменты, там много чего готового есть

Пускай он и справивал про аутлайн, но люди не всегда спрашивают то, что им на самом деле нужно. Зачестую ясно, что человек смотрит не в ту сторону и приходится годать в какую нужно, но в данном случае человек написал, для чего ему это нужно.

@Yaroslav, так а чем мой ответ не подходит к его вопросу? У тебя был комментарий про шейдеры, предложенные инструменты как раз используют готовые шейдеры)
